# View, Viewgroup, onClick, getChildAt problem

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an activity with multiple cards that flip on click.

I have a Framelayout(the card) with two other Framelayouts(the two sides of the card) in it, like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:onClick="flipCard">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_back1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/card_back" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_front1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <include layout="@layout/card_front" />

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have the "flipCard" method that SHOULD start the objectanimators and sets their targets to the two framelayouts(sides of the card).

However, the partent framelayout(the card) is the view that calls the "flipcard" method with it's onclick, but within the "flipcard" method I need to set the targets to the childviews. I thought of using .getChildAt() method for this, but I am not able to make it work.

flipCard method:

```
public void flipCard(View view) {
    if (!mIsBackVisible) {
        mSetRightOut.setTarget(view.getChildAt(1));
        mSetLeftIn.setTarget(view.getChildAt(0));
        mSetRightOut.start();
        mSetLeftIn.start();
        mIsBackVisible = true;
    } else {
        mSetRightOut.setTarget(view.getChildAt(0));
        mSetLeftIn.setTarget(view.getChildAt(1));
        mSetRightOut.start();
        mSetLeftIn.start();
        mIsBackVisible = false;
    }
}
```

If I change the flipCard method to "flipCard(ViewGroup Viewgroup) it doesn't work because the onClick in the xml is looking for a method that takes a View and not a ViewGroup.

I need the onClick to be on the parent Framelayout, but I need to get the child framelayouts through it somehow.

How can I make my original idea work, or if I can't, what other solution should I try?

EDIT: The solution was as simple as putting "ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;" at the start of the flipCard method.

Comment: you can try calling `view.findViewById(R.id.card_front1)` instead of `getChildAt()`

Comment: @Alexander The problem with that is, that I have multiple cards, not just one. I need to call the childs of the frontview that gets clicked, not allways card_front1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as putting "ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;" at the start of the flipCard method.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the below code it will worked i have use color to show there you
>   have to put your color

layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOne"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTwo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

> Demo.Java

```
 public class demo extends AppCompatActivity {

private FrameLayout llOne, llTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_demo);
    initBasic();
}

private void initBasic() {
    llOne = findViewById(R.id.llOne);
    llTwo = findViewById(R.id.llTwo);
    llOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            llOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    llTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            llOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: The problem with this is that the animations need to start for both of the card sides. That means the onclick has to be on the parent frameview. When the card spins, there is an animation for both sides of the card. If we change it so that we only click one side of a card then ony one side will animate. Aslo I have 18+ cards on screen. With this I would have to create an onclick for each card, and even that wouldn't work because of how the objectanimation is.